# WebDriver Firefox profile not working after IEDriverServer setup

Tags: python, internet-explorer, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I've been using webdriver.Firefox() for my test cases, but wanted to test on IE. I downloaded IEDriverServer, added it to my PATH and ran the IE test case successfully. However, when I then tried switching back to Firefox and running the same test case, the Firefox browser opened up, but nothing happened, and then I received this error:

```
C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py:85: 
ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket object, fd=280, family=2, type=1, proto=0>
 while not utils.is_connectable(self.profile.port):
C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py:85: 
ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket object, fd=532, family=2, type=1, proto=0>
 while not utils.is_connectable(self.profile.port):
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_ytest (__main__.Ytest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\K\workspace\PythonTesting\src\RecipeTest.py", line 11, in setUp
 self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
 self.binary, timeout),
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
 self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 51, in launch_browser
 self._wait_until_connectable()
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 95, in _wait_until_connectable
 self.profile.path, self._get_firefox_output()))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: "Can't load the profile.     Profile Dir: c:\\users\\k\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmp0vf9hl Firefox output: b'*** LOG addons.xpi: startup\\r\\n*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local\\r\\n*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share\\r\\n*** WARN addons.xpi: Ignoring missing add-on in C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Wajam\\\\Firefox\\\\{5a95a9e0-59dd-4314-bd84-4d18ca83a0e2}.xpi\\r\\n*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges\\r\\n*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found\\r\\n'" 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 35.208s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I've removed the PATH to IEDriverSetup and went so far as to remove it. I restarted Eclipse (I'm using it to run my Python/WebDriver tests) and restarted IE and Firefox to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am using Python 3.3 to develop my test cases, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please place your code in your question, just the bit around where you initialise the driver will be fine. However, without this, there is not much we can do. I'd also double check there are no IEDriverServer or IE processes open in the Task Manager's process list.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a  __*pycache*__  directory among your files?
I removed it. No error once it is removed.

PS. python 3.3.2